# how to Display powerpoint as slide show on page in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, wiki-pages

I have power point presentation on document library and want to show this presentation as a slide show on the wiki page in share point. How it should be done??
I have tried this **Picture Library Slideshow Web Part** but in this picture library and library view is not selectable" what i need to do. 
Is there any other option available to do it. 
please help me with it.

Thanks  In Advance

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is use the File Viewer web part. Just add a file, choose Upload, and upload the file (or upload to your SharePoint site and link from there). Poof! PowerPoint slide show.